# From the database I am trying to display a single common name using label please guide me I am a beginner in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am trying to make a feedback form where I want to show the name which is inserted n number of times.

My DataBase has for example 9 duplicate names as feedback was input for that same person 9 times and I want to display it on the result that common name.

Please help me out to complete the code/solution or Correct the code and get the result.

SQL QUERY IS RUNNING PROPERLY IT IS SELECTING THE SINGLE DATA FROM DATABASE BUT HOW TO SHOW THIS ON WEBPAGE

```
public void cal_F2name()
{       
    string oracledb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP****))(****))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SID = ORCL));";
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oracledb);
    conn.Open();

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    OracleDataAdapter da1 = new OracleDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT (F2NAME) FROM CMDC_FEEDBACK WHERE PRG_NAME ='" + cb_prg_name.SelectedValue + "'";

    da1.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da1.Fill(ds1);
    name = Convert.ToString(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());

    Label58.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}",name);


    conn.Close();
}
```

[image: IMAGE OF DATABASE]

[image: IMAGE OF QUERY IS RUNNING FINE]

Comment: Your query seems to be resulting 2 records, one an empty record and two actual result. There seems to be an empty record with your filter conditions. Also, it is better to use stored procedures instead of inline queries to avoid security issues.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function and **NEVER** build a query using string concatenation of user input (otherwise you will be introducing SQL injection vulnerabilities into your code), use bind variables instead: `SELECT DISTINCT F2NAME FROM CMDC_FEEDBACK WHERE PRG_NAME = :prgname`

Answer (score 0):

try using below code, i have made some change in sql query to get only single record as result.

```
public void cal_F2name()
    {       
        string oracledb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP****))(****))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SID = ORCL));";
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oracledb);
        conn.Open();

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    OracleDataAdapter da1 = new OracleDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT max(DISTINCT (F2NAME)) FROM CMDC_FEEDBACK WHERE PRG_NAME ='" + cb_prg_name.SelectedValue + "' AND F2NAME<>'' AND F2NAME IS NOT NULL" ;

    da1.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da1.Fill(ds1);
    name = Convert.ToString(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());

    Label58.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}",name);


    conn.Close();
}
```

i have not check but it will work, if you result binding to lable is correct.

Comment: In Oracle `''` and `NULL` are identical so `F2NAME<>''` is the same as `F2NAME <> NULL` which will always be false (as `NULL` is never equal or not equal to anything else, including another `NULL`).

Comment: Also, **NEVER** build queries using string concatenation of user input as it introduces SQL injection vulnerabilities; use a bind variable instead.